# AWS Control Tower could not delete some account trails error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations, aws-control-tower

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6rls.png)

I'm getting this error in Control Tower.

I've tried to re-register all OU's, update landing zone but i left AWS CloudTrail disabled because we have a solution to manage CloudTrail trails implemented. Is This issue related to this? Do I have any option to get rid of this error?

Comment: Same issue. Any solution yet?